# How to use .dockeringore file with different environments?

Tags: angular, docker

I am a newbie at Docker just started learning it.

So I have three build files for an Angular app. The Angular app is just a startup template created using ng new 'projectName'

```
Dockerfile.dev
Dockerfile.qa
Dockerfile.prod
```

Now these files work. I have tested them.

Sample Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /srv/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

But the issue I am facing is how to use the .dockerignore file to exclude the node_modules

I already have the .dockerignore file
Which is just a copy of my .gitignore file.

This .dockerignore file works with Dockerfile but not with Dockerfile.qa/dev/prod

I use the following commands to build it

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.qa .
```

But the files I want to ignore aren't ignored and are copied over using the

```
Copy . .
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is the .dockerignore file in the same directory as the Dockerfiles?

Comment: Yes it is in the same directory and my angular build file is at 500MB+

Comment: @Wander3r added Dockerfile.dev

Comment: Don't know if this works, but you can create another dockerignore with the file name "Dockerfile.qa.dockerignore" and have the same contents as your original .dockerignore and try building the Dockerfile.qa and check.

Comment: Multiple per-environment images like this isn't usually a best practice – are you running untested code in production, because you only ran the "QA" image in a test environment?  If you can reduce this to a single Dockerfile then this ambiguity goes away.

Comment: @Wander3r thanks for the help I followed this and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

1. From Docker 19.03, you can try [Docker BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#to-enable-buildkit-builds), to set the DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 environment variable when invoking the docker build command:
   `$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .`

You also need to prefix the name of your `.dockerignore` file with the Dockerfile name.
If your Dockerfile is called `Dockerfile.dev` the ignore file needs to be called `Dockerfile.dev.dockerignore`.

> The Docker client tries to load `<dockerfile-name>.dockerignore` first and then falls back to `.dockerignore` if it can't be found. So docker `build -f Dockerfile.dev .` first tries to load `Dockerfile.dev.dockerignore`.

2. Split your build folder into `subdirectories` that each have their own `Dockerfile` and `.dockerignore` files: **`dev/qa/prod`**